# Is there a way to prebuild the .rst files generated by autodoc in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, read-the-docs

I have a project for which I've build a set of .rst files with `sphinx.ext.apidoc` that extracts documentation from my project's docstrings.

Those files look like the following:

```
Submodules
----------
.. toctree::
   mymodule.submodule

Module contents
---------------

.. automodule:: mymodule
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

`make html` builds the documentation properly on my computer, but requires me to edit the `conf.py` file to add my project to the python system path, so that it finds properly the modules mentioned in the .rst files when autodoc tries to import them.

However, when I try to build the documentation on the readthedocs, autodoc is unable to find the referenced modules because I don't know what path needs to be added to the python system path for the autodoc to properly find the project modules.

I was wondering if it would be possible to pre-build the .rst files with autodoc in the local environment, so that they don't contain any calls to autodoc anymore  and then upload them to readthedocs, so that there is no need to run the autodoc extension there.

If there is no way to do this, what would be the proper way of solving that problem?

Comment: Do you not have a `setup.py` to tell RTD etc how to install the project?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same issue, with a project which is cython based, so (I guess) impossible to build on RTD.

Comment: Yes, I ended up writing a blog post about it back then: http://andreikucharavy.com/L3Cache/parsing-sphinx/ I will update the answer below. The main idea is to use mock modules as it is suggested here: http://docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering, the solution was provided by the [readthedocs FAQ](http://docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html): In order for the modules that depend on C and cannot be easily installed by `pip` inside the `venv` readthedoc builds, it is necessary to mock them and all sub-modules you import in the `conf.py` file within the `myproject/docs/source` directory of your documentation (or wherever your Sphinx's `conf.py` is).
in my case the code was the following:

```
if on_rtd:
    warn('debug -syspath -edit: %s'%os.path.abspath('../..'))
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))

    class Mock(MagicMock):

        @classmethod
        def __getattr__(cls, name):
            return Mock()

        @classmethod
        def __getitem__(cls, name):
            return Mock()


    MOCK_MODULES = ['numpy',
                    'scikit-learn',
                    'pymongo',
                    'cython',
                    'Cython',
                    'matplotlib',
                    'matplotlib.pyplot',
                    'scipy',
                    'scipy.stats',
                    'scipy.sparse',
                    'scipy.sparse.linalg',
                    'scipy.sparse.csgraph',
                    'scikits',
                    'scikits.sparse',
                    'scikits.sparse.cholmod',
                    'sklearn',
                    'sklearn.cluster',
                    'python-Levenshtein'
                    'levenstein',
                    'python.levenstein'
                    ]

    for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES:
        sys.modules.update({mod_name: Mock()})
```